# Failed to resolve module specifier "socket.io-client". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io, socket.io-client

I am creating a chat application using socket.io.
I stuck into a error.if i removing the requiring socket.io-client the rest of the code running .but when i requiring the socket.io the it shows error "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "socket.io". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"."
I tried too many thing still facing this error pls help!
I tried insted of import,
require socket.io-client.
and also import the socket.io-client.

```
    // server side
    const app = require('express')();
    const server = require('http').createServer(app);
    const io = require("socket.io")(server,{
      cors: {
        origin: ["https://example.com", "https://dev.example.com"],
        allowedHeaders: ["my-custom-header"],
        credentials: true
      }
    });

    // app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    //   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    // });


    server.listen(3000, () => {
      console.log('listening on *:3000...');
    });
enter code here
    io.on('connection',socket=>{
      consol.log("connection to server",socket);

        socket.on('new-user-joined',name=>{
            users[socket.id] = name;
            socket.broadcast.emit('user-joined',name);
        });

        socket.on('send',message=>{
            socket.broadcast.emit('recive',{message:message,name:users[socket.id]})
        });
    })
```

```js
    //client side 
    import { io } from "socket.io-client";
    const socket = io();

    const form=document.getElementById('send-container');
    const messageInput=document.getElementById('messageInp');
    const messageContainer=document.querySelector(".container");

    const name = prompt("Enter your name to join:");

    const append=(message,position)=>{
        const messageElement=document.createElement('div');
        messageElement.innerText=message;
        messageElement.classList.add('message');
        messageElement.classList.add(position);
        messageContainer.append(messageElement);
    }

    form.addEventListener('submit',(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        const message=messageInput.value;
        append(`you: ${message}`,'right')
        socket.emit('send',message);
        messageInput.value='';
    })
     

    socket.emit('new-user-joined', name);
    socket.on('user-joined',name=>{
        append(`${name} joined the chat`,'right')
    })

    socket.on('receiv',data=>{
        append(`${data.name}:${data.message}`,'left')
    })
```

```css
    .logo{
        display:block;
        margin:auto;
        width: 50px;
        height:50px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius:40px;
    }
     body{
        height: 100vh;
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(85, 57, 57) , rgb(60, 82, 110));
    } 
    .container{
        background-color:rgb(194, 160, 160);
        max-width: 800px;
        height:400px;
        margin: 10px;
        margin:auto;
        overflow-y:auto;
    }
    .message{
        background-color: gray;
        padding: auto;
        width: 24%;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 17px 12px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius: 10px;

    }
    .left{
        float:left;
        clear:both
    }
    .right{
        float: right;
        clear:both
    }
    .btn{
         cursor:pointer; 
        border:2px solid black;
        border-radius:6px
    }
    #send-container{
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        margin:auto;
        width: 90%;
        
    }
    #messageInp{

        width:62.1%;
        border:2px solid black;
        border-radius: 6px;
        
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>pro-chat realdtime socakat ios</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <img class="logo" src="chat.jpg" alt="">
        </nav>
        <div class="container"> 
            <div class="message right">Aniket:kase ho bhai</div>
            <div class="message left">Raju:thik hai bhai</div>
        </div>
        <div class="send">
            <form action="#" id="send-container" >
                <input type="text" name="messageInp" id="messageInp">
                <button class="btn" type="submit">Send</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <script  src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script  src="js/client.js" type="module"></script> //here it showing the error
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
(type="/module")
```

Instead of:

```
(type="module")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-3.0.1.min.js"></script>
```

Use this as your script file, paste it in the html file and don't import or require anything in the server side

Answer (score 0):

To load the client library, use this code:

> ```
>    <script  src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
> ```

… which you already have.

Don't `import` it: You already have it.

Don't `require` it: You aren't running the code on Node.js *and* you already have it.

Comment: sir, after removing the importing part from client side, it shoing error "io not define".

Comment: Check the Network tab of the browser's developer tools. Make sure /socket.io/socket.io.js is loading correctly.

Comment: sir, it is not loading the /socket.io/socket.io.js , plese go through the code and can you give me the proper solution where i am lagging , if it possible,